# How to find weighted mean in series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have series like this that I have achieved using group by:

```
Job         Salary    
Teacher     15       3
            23       4
            28       5

Doctor      10       3 
            35       2
            40       1
```

How can I calculate average salary for teacher or doctor?

Average salary calculation formula for teacher is: (15 * 3) + (23 * 4) + (28 * 5) / (3+4+5)

Comment: The arithemtic expression you present seems incorrect to me. Did you mean a weighted mean `(15*3 + 23*4 + 28*5) / (3+4+5)`...?

Comment: Yes, sorry I will update the question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ...its just a general math question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for simplicity create DataFrame in first step, multiply columns, aggregate `sum` and last divide columns like:

```
df1 = df.reset_index(name='count')

df1['new'] = df1['Salary'].mul(df1['count'])

df1 = df1.groupby('Job').sum()

df2 = df1['new'].div(df1['count']).reset_index(name='out')
print (df2)
       Job        out
0   Doctor  23.333333
1  Teacher  23.083333
```

Like @Mark Wang mentioned, is possible use `np.average` like:

```
df2 =  df.reset_index(name='count').groupby('Job').apply(lambda x: np.average(x['Salary'], weights=x['count'])).reset_index(name='out')
print(df2)
       Job        out
0   Doctor  23.333333
1  Teacher  23.083333
```

Comment: There's this `np.average`, which differs from `np.mean` in that it takes weights.  That's how scikit-learn implements its sample weighting